# JSDOC for classes in Javascript Closure or Anonymous Function

Tags: function, anonymous, jsdoc

I wanted to add jsdoc annotations to my AngularJS codes, so i tried :

**PageFactory.js**

```
/**
 * Creates an instance of PageFactory.
 *
 * @constructor
 * @this {PageFactory}
 * 
*/
function PageFactory() {
}

angular.module ( 'app' ).factory ('PageFactory', PageFactory);
```

The above works fine and produces the expected jsdoc output.  But when i enclose this codes in an anonymous function like this :

**PageFactory.js**

```
(function (){

    /**
     * Creates an instance of PageFactory.
     *
     * @constructor
     * @this {PageFactory}
     * 
    */
    function PageFactory() {
    }

    angular.module ( 'app' ).factory ('PageFactory', PageFactory);

})();
```

The generated jsdoc html output is blank and no documentation on PageFactory class.

Is theres a way to make jsdoc work with anonymous functions or to work with my second code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@lends <global>` like this:

```
(/** @lends <global> */ function (){
// etc... the rest remains the same.
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this helped. though the classes has ~ at front but it's as good as what i wanted.

Comment: Glad to help. See the [namepath documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html) to see what the `~` and the other symbols mean.